# How to do data cleansing in Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I just started Scala on Spark, so I am not sure if my question is workable or should I turn to other solution/tool:

I have a text file for word counting and sorting, here is the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0qXqpUMxJDKa0hMMDRoZVpCSTQ/view?usp=sharing).

1. I load the file into HDFS
2. I then use the following code in Scala to do the counting:

   ```
   val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/Peter")
   val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(p => (p,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).sortByKey(true,1)
   counts.saveAsTextFile("Peter_SortedOutput6")
   ```
3. I checked the result on hdfs by `hdfs dfs -cat hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root/Peter_SortedOutput5/part-00000`

Part of the result is posted here for the convenience of reading:

> ((For,1)
>   ((not,1)
>   (1,8)
>   (10,8)
>   (11,8)
>   (12,8)
>   (13,8)
>   (14,8)
>   (15,7)
>   (16,7)
>   (17,7)
>   (18,7)
>   (19,6)
>   (2,8)
>   (20,5)
>   (21,5)
>   (22,4)
>   (23,2)
>   (24,2)
>   (25,2)
>   (3,8)
>   (4,8)
>   (5,8)
>   (6,8)
>   (7,8)
>   (8,8)
>   (9,8)
>   (Abraham,,1)
>   (According,1)
>   (Amen.,4)
>   (And,19)
>   (As,5)
>   (Asia,,1)
>   (Babylon,,1)
>   (Balaam,1)
>   (Be,2)
>   (Because,1)

First, this is really not what I expect, I want the result showing in the desc order of count.
Second, there are result like the following:

> (God,25)
>   (God's,1)
>   (God,,9)
>   (God,),1)
>   (God.,6)
>   (God:,2)
>   (God;,2)
>   (God?,1)

How to do some cleansing in the split so these occurrences can be grouped into one (God, 47)

Thank you very much.

Comment: You are splitting on the single space and not stripping punctuation, so that explains why you don't see all grouped keys

Comment: And you are sorting by key, so it's not clear why you did that if you want to sort by value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a course [BerkeleyX: CS105x Introduction to Apache Spark](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1%3ABerkeleyX%2BCS105x%2B1T2016/info) on edx.org by Berkerly&Databricks. One of the assignment is doing word count.

The steps are

- remove punctuation, by replace "[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+" with "", or not include numbers "[^A-Za-z\s]+"
- trim all spaces
- lower all words

we can add extra step like

- remove stop words

Code as follows

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split

// val reg = raw"[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+" // with numbers

val reg = raw"[^A-Za-z\s]+" // no numbers
val lines = sc.textFile("peter.txt").
    map(_.replaceAll(reg, "").trim.toLowerCase).toDF("line")
val words = lines.select(split($"line", " ").alias("words"))

val remover = new StopWordsRemover()
      .setInputCol("words")
      .setOutputCol("filtered")

val noStopWords = remover.transform(words)

val counts = noStopWords.select(explode($"filtered")).map(word =>(word, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_+_)

// from word -> num to num -> word
val mostCommon = counts.map(p => (p._2, p._1)).sortByKey(false, 1)

mostCommon.take(5)
```

Comment: Thank you Rockie, what is the best practice to exclude words like "an", "a", "the"....?

Comment: @mdivk, the term you're probably looking for is "stop words".  Lots of hits for that (+ s"park word occurrence") on google.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Thanks to point out. I added stop words remover to the answer

Comment: Thanks. @Rockie Yang: 1. Why scala complains the format [here](https://snag.gy/VpSDJM.jpg) while it was taken in [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_regular_expressions.htm) ? 2. How do I exclude the counting of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Clean data by use of `replaceAll`:

```
val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.trim.toLowerCase.split(" ").replaceAll("[$,?+.;:\'s\\W\\d]", ""));
```

sort by value in scala API:

```
.map(item => item.swap) // interchanges position of entries in each tuple
.sortByKey(true, 1) // 1st arg configures ascending sort, 2nd arg configures one task
.map(item => item.swap)
```

sort by value in python API:

```
.map(lambda (a, b): (b, a)) \
.sortByKey(1, 1) \ # 1st arg configures ascending sort, 2nd configures 1 task
.map(lambda (a, b): (b, a))
```

Code should look like this (*you may see syntax error, please fix if any*):

```
val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/Peter")
val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.trim.toLowerCase.split(" ").replaceAll("[$,?+.;:\'s\\W\\d]", ""))
                 .map(p => (p,1))
                 .reduceByKey(_+_)
                 .map(rec => rec.swap)
                 .sortByKey(true, 1)
                 .map(rec => rec.swap)

counts.saveAsTextFile("Peter_SortedOutput6")
```

see [scala_regular_expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_regular_expressions.htm) - for what `[\\W]` or `[\\d]` or `[;:',.?]` mean.

Comment: I'd switch the regex to `[^\w]+`, personally

Comment: how about `[\W]`? : )

Comment: it includes _, perhaps in word case, it should be excluded as well

Comment: mdivk wants `God's` to be counted as `God` so use of `[^\w]` would not convert `God's` as `Gods` - it would not give expected results

Comment: also updated as per @Rockie Yang's suggestions in his answer - trim and lower all  words.

Comment: `(?:\'s$|[\W]+)` might still be better. You probably don't want to strip apostrophe s in the middle of a word

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. It's `(?:\'s$|[\\w]+)`, not `(?:\'s$|[\\W]+)`, note there should be two  \\ , and `W` will return `'` only, I didn't do it in hadoop scala but actually tested it in [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: still trying to test out how to exclude numbers in the text file, adding `\\D` doesn't work. :(

Comment: if you want to replace numbers than you have to use `\\d` not `\\D` - see updates in answer.